# ADDRESS of cell found from LOOKUP function

Tags: excel, lookup-tables

What I need is the address of the cell found in a `LOOKUP` function.

I have a table with various client orders and payments. `tbl_main`
The columns relevant to my question are `[Receive Date]`, `[Credit]`, `[Balance]`.

> (The Balance Column is auto generated).

Here's the `[Credit]` column:

[image]

The first of each month is every client's payment `Due Date`, where he needs to pay for any work done during the month. So I need a **CELL** to show me what the `due date` is, based on these three things:

1. Find the last cell with a value in the `[Credit]` column. This alone I figured out: `=LOOKUP(2,1/(tbl_main[Credit]<>""),tbl_main[Credit])`
2. Find the `[Balance]` column on that same row. If it's a negative number, continue.

   > (client owes money on the first of next month)
3. Find the `[Receive Date]` column on that same row and calculate when his due date is

   > (when the first of next month is).

This Alone I already figured out: `=EOMONTH(B328,0)+1`but, of course, the `B328` is my test cell. I would need my formula to be able to figure out the `row index 4`. Display this `due date` in a cell somewhere.

I just can't figure out how to write a formula to accomplish this without VBA.

I tried combining various methods of `LOOKUP` and `MATCH`, but get `#N/A` results.

Can someone help with this?

Comment: Have you tried using a [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)?

Comment: If you have the row, you should be able to use `Offset`, `Indirect` or `Index` to find the corresponding cells on the same row. I would encourage looking into those.

Comment: Offset would be wrong if I add or delete columns in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code I figured out. It's specific to my own needs but maybe someone with the same question can harvest some code from it that will help.

```
Sub GetPaymentDueStatus()

'#################################
'Get \ Set "Payment Due" field
'#################################

'If not viewing one client - exit sub
If ActiveSheet.Range("SelectedClient") = "ALL CLIENTS" Then

    Range("PaymentDueStatus") = "N\A"
    Range("PaymentDueDate") = "N\A"

    Exit Sub

Else

    'Client has no debt
    If Range("Total_All") >= 0 Then

        Range("PaymentDueStatus") = "SETTLED"
        Range("PaymentDueDate") = "N\A"

            'Client has debt - check if on time or overdue
            Else

                '#################################
                'Start Calculation
                '#################################

                Dim rownumCredit As Long
                Dim colCredit As Long
                Dim rngCredit As Range

                Dim LastPaymentDate As Date
                Dim MonthAfterPayment As Date

                Set rngCredit = Range("rng_credit").Find(what:="*", LookIn:=xlValues, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)

                rownumCredit = rngCredit.Row
                colCredit = rngCredit.Column

                '#################################
                'Calculate the Last Payment date
                'if it's ovedue
                '#################################

                'Get date of last payment
                LastPaymentDate = Cells(rownumCredit, Range("rng_recDate_main").Column)

                'Get next first of the month from last payment
                MonthAfterPayment = WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Cells(rownumCredit, Range("rng_recDate_main").Column), 0) + 1

                'Check if overdue
                If Month(MonthAfterPayment) <= Month(Date) Then

                    Range("PaymentDueStatus") = "OVERDUE"

                Else

                    Range("PaymentDueStatus") = "ON TIME"

                End If

                Range("PaymentDueDate") = MonthAfterPayment


    End If

End If

End Sub
```